# python regex to match string between all literal characters

Tags: python, regex, python-re

i am new to python regex i am trying to write a regular expression to match a string between character which are literals

````py
my_string = "```,null,")]}'\n[[\"102fb5\",\"```"
````

What I want is `102fb5`.

The regex I have written:

````py
"```n\[\[\\\"((?:.|\n)*?)\\"```"
````

Comment: try this ```([A-Za-z0-9]{6})```

Comment: What do you mean by "literals"?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you use a Python raw string, it would make your RegEx more readable, in the sense that you won't need to escape every backslash:

````py
QUERY = r'```n\[\[\"((?:.|\n)*?)\"```'
````

However, I'm not sure why you're bothering to match the entire list-like structure, when you could just search for the "literals" themselves by identifying their quotation marks:

````py
# \"(.*?)\"
# Match escaped quotation mark: \"
# Match the literal text: .*?
# Match the other escaped quotation mark: \"

>>> re.findall(r'\"(.*?)\"', '''```,null,")]}'\n[[\"102fb5\",```"'\n[[\"102fb5\",\"```''')

['102fb5', '102fb5']
````